# ACF get post Id?

Tags: plugins

From ACF plugin, I select on one page using get_post($args):

```
$args = array(
  'suppress_filters' => 0,
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'sort_order' => 'ASC',
  'sort_column' => 'post_title',
  'post_type' => 'my_type',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
);

$my_types = get_posts($args);
```

Then iterating over $types I construct an < ul > of the things that are returned as my type and for each I also get the according id

```
foreach ($my_types as $my_type) {
    $title = $my_type->post_title;
    $slug = $my_type->post_name;
    $thisid = $my_type->ID;
    $permalink = get_permalink($thisid);
    $fields = get_fields($thisid);
 }
```

Each li get's an link to $permalink and a picture of that item: $fields['photo']

```
<a class="pop" href="<?php echo $permalink ?>">
```

Now on that $permalink-page, I again get the fields

```
$fields = get_fields();
```

ACF documentation says, get_fields "Defaults to the current post." when no ID is given.

The problem is now, that $get_fields() doesn't contain any ID. I can use an ID to get specific post, or it just gives the "current post" when no ID was given. It contains the defined ACFs but no Id I could select on.

How can I get $thisid from get_fields() so I can pass it as a parameter?

I'd need to create on each $permalink page of an item a link to a contact form which needs to get added to it's URL the ID of that thing.

```
<a href="https://example.com/contacts/form/?id=<?php echo $thisid; ?>">
// ("contacts" is a CPT content type)
```

So I can do in the javascript on the form page perform a get_fields($id); to add stuff like name or photo from the fields to the contact form.

The only idea I have so far is to add to $permalink the ID as a get parameter:

```
<a class="pop" href="<?php echo $permalink ?>?id=<?php echo $thisid;?>">
```

And then on the $permalink page get the parameter via

```
$thisid = get_query_var('id');
<a href="https://example.com/contact/form/?id=<?php echo $thisid; ?>">
```

I know it's rather complex but I just want to know if there's a better way within ACF than adding the ID to each link.

Comment: "I'd need to create on each $permalink page of an item a link to a contact form" - I think you're looking for either `get_the_ID()` or `get_queried_object_id()`.

Comment: No, get_the_ID() gives the ID of the page, not of the fields.

Comment: So, `<a href="https://example.com/contacts/form/?id=<?php the_ID(); ?>">` or `<a href="https://example.com/contacts/form/?id=<?php echo get_queried_object_id(); ?>">` doesn't work?